# Can I see when a page has been redirected?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using node.js and express for a little proxy server. Everything works pretty well except when I visit a page that gets redirected.

Step 1: I visit a page:

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

Its passed through to http://whatever.com/ that contains a Classic ASP-page that uses a normal redirect:

```
<% Response.Redirect("/login/") %>
```

The page gets redirected and I get the html from the /login/ folder but my browser is still on localhost:3000. This means some links to the javscript and css-files doesnt work.

I would have expected the browser to have changed to localhost:3000/login because of that redirect, but it doesn't. My code looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var concat = require('concat-stream');
var request = require('request');
var app = express();

app.all("*", function (req, resp) {

    var url = 'http://whatever.com' + req.url;

    console.log('fetching:' + url);

    var write = concat(function(response) {     
        resp.end(response);
    });

    request.get(url)
        .on('response',
            function (response) {}
        ).pipe(write);

});

app.listen(3000);
```

I haven't been able to find anything about it, hardly people with the same problem. Getting the data from the redirected page isn't the issue - it's performing the actual redirect for the client so I don't parse out html on a wrong URL.

Any help?